# Access Flash Player global settings (Firefox)

Tags: firefox

I am trying to access the Flash player global setting however when I right click it instantly closes the options and opens a new tab then goes to the [Flash Player help site](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html).

On Ubuntu this issue can be resolved by re-loading Flash Player via synaptic however this doesn’t work on elementary OS … any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You should stay on [that website](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html) as it in fact contains the Flash Player global settings (the flash element at the top). Quoting:

> The Settings Manager that you see above is not an image; it is the actual Settings Manager. Click the tabs to see different panels, and click the options in the panels to change your Adobe Flash Player settings.